# How to insert HTML into Response body using .NET Core Middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack, asp.net-core-middleware

I've been trying to cobble up some middleware that will allow me to measure the processing time on a request. [This](https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/using-aspnet-cores-middleware-to-modify-response-body) example gave me a good starting point, but I've run into trouble.

In the code below, I am able to measure the process time and insert it in a div (using HTML Agility Pack). However, the original contents of the page get duplicated. I think I'm doing something incorrectly with the `context.Response.Body` property in `UpdateHtml()`, but cannot figure out what it is. (I made some comments in the code.) If you see anything that looks incorrect, could you please let me know?

Thanks.

```
public class ResponseMeasurementMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseMeasurementMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
        {
            var responseTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var newContent = string.Empty;
            var existingBody = context.Response.Body;
            string updatedHtml = await UpdateHtml(responseTime, context);

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(updatedHtml);
        });

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private async Task<string> UpdateHtml(long responseTime, HttpContext context)
    {
        var newContent = string.Empty;
        var existingBody = context.Response.Body;
        string updatedHtml = "";
        //I think I'm doing something incorrectly in this using...
        using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = newBody;

            await _next(context);

            context.Response.Body = existingBody;
            newBody.Position = 0;

            newContent = await new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEndAsync();
            updatedHtml = CreateDataNode(newContent, responseTime);
        }

        return updatedHtml;
    }

    private string CreateDataNode(string originalHtml, long responseTime)
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(originalHtml);
        HtmlNode testNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode($"<div><h2>Inserted using Html Agility Pack: Response Time: {responseTime.ToString()} ms.</h2><div>");
        var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        htmlBody.InsertBefore(testNode, htmlBody.FirstChild);

        string rawHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; //using this results in a page that displays my inserted HTML correctly, but duplicates the original page content.
        //rawHtml = "some text"; uncommenting this results in a page with the correct format: this text, followed by the original contents of the page

        return rawHtml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For duplicated html, it is caused by `await _next(context);` in `UpdateHtml` which will invoke the rest middlware like MVC to handle the requests and response.

Withtout `await _next(context);`, you should not modify the Reponse body in `context.Response.OnStarting`.

For a workaround, I would suggest you place the `ResponseMeasurementMiddleware` as the first middleware and then calculate the time like

```
public class ResponseMeasurementMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseMeasurementMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;
        var newBody = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = newBody;

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        long responseTime = 0;
        watch.Start();
        await _next(context);
        //// read the new body
        // read the new body
        responseTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        newBody.Position = 0;
        var newContent = await new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEndAsync();
        // calculate the updated html
        var updatedHtml = CreateDataNode(newContent, responseTime);
        // set the body = updated html
        var updatedStream = GenerateStreamFromString(updatedHtml);
        await updatedStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
        context.Response.Body = originalBody;

    }
    public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
    private string CreateDataNode(string originalHtml, long responseTime)
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(originalHtml);
        HtmlNode testNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode($"<div><h2>Inserted using Html Agility Pack: Response Time: {responseTime.ToString()} ms.</h2><div>");
        var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        htmlBody.InsertBefore(testNode, htmlBody.FirstChild);

        string rawHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml; //using this results in a page that displays my inserted HTML correctly, but duplicates the original page content.
                                                         //rawHtml = "some text"; uncommenting this results in a page with the correct format: this text, followed by the original contents of the page

        return rawHtml;
    }
}
```

And register `ResponseMeasurementMiddleware` like

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ResponseMeasurementMiddleware>();
    //rest middlwares
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

For this way `app.UseMiddleware<ResponseMeasurementMiddleware>();`, the action will be last opertion before sending the response, and then processing time would be suitable for processing time.

Comment: Thank you! You saved a lot of time for me. Is it a problem, that the MemoryStream doesn't get closed anywhere? I did it with a using-statement before, but got every time the error message that "few bytes are written (0 of x)". I think it was, because the MemoryStream got closed after the using statement ...